# Which testing tool should I be aware of as a fresher in testing?

Tags: software-testing, unit-tests, quality-assurance, performance-testing

I am looking for testing tools which are prominent in the banking and aviation sector so that I can be familiar with their working and utilization.

Comment: Those are two very disparate sectors. I would not imagine that this is much overlap in testing. The only overlap that I can think of in terms of architecture is real-time, low latency. Normally, your employer would tell you what tools to use, so I will guess that you are preparing yourself for interviews and wan to show familiarity with the test tools? This is a very board question, and ids likely to be closed if you do not provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to banking and/or aviation my expectation is that the companies already have defined toolchains and frameworks and the exact tools differ from company to company. The only way of identifying is looking for current and historical QA roles requirements and take a look at the programming languages and tools which are in scope.

In general I don't think that tool really matters as it's just a "tool" and despite the differences they serve the same purpose.

Given you have good understanding of:

- [Algorithms](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-an-algorithm-in-programming-definition-examples-analysis.html)
- [Data Structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)
- [Operating Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Operating_Systems)
- [Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

You should be able to pick up any programming language and any testing tool.

When it comes to some form of industry standards:

- [Web Applications Testing](https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/best-automation-testing-tools-for-2018-top-10-reviews-8a4a19f664d2):

  - [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)
  - [Watir](http://watir.com/) and derivatives
  - [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) and other JS-based frameworks
- [Mobile Applications Testing](https://medium.com/intuz/top-10-automated-testing-tools-for-mobile-apps-8d9380e1757f):

  - [Appium](http://appium.io/)
  - [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso)
  - [XCUITest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/user_interface_tests)
- [Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/):

  - [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
  - [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
  - [Locust](https://locust.io/)
- etc.